# Laravel Validation of Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Laravel Help with validation
Hi everyone I want to validate an array of a foreign key to make sure it exists I am doing

```
'activities'    => 'required|array',
'activities.*' => 'exists:admin_activities,id',
```

but it's skipping this validation

any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You can validate each element of an array in Laravel with "dot notation" to  For example, to validate that each id in a given array input field is exists in admin_activities , you may do the following:

```
'activities.*.id' => 'required|exists:admin_activities,id',
```